# О значении и происхождении поговорок "сойти с рук", "с рук долой"

Tags: пословицы

В русском языке много поговорок, связанных с руками, при этом в них присутствует как положительная, так и отрицательная коннотация.

***Сошло с рук.***

***Нам только с рук долой, а с ног — хоть собака тащи!***

Почему две эти поговорки выражают отрицательное отношение? Зачем во второй поговорке появляется собака и что значит ***с ног***?

Answer (score 2):

**Сошло с рук**

Обычно так говорят, когда некорректное поведение человека (в том числе свое собственное) может создать неприятные последствия. Но обстоятельства складываются так хорошо, что никаких проблем не возникает.

Все проступки и связанные с ними возможные неприятности **сходят (как бы стекают) с рук.** Такая удачливость часто кажется несправедливой, отсюда и негативная оценка, а в отношении себя это звучит как предупреждение.

**Нам только с рук долой, а с ног — хоть собака тащи!**

Эта поговорка тоже о проблемах. **Решать их можно по-разному:** или основательно, устраняя причину, или поверхностно, только на некоторое  время. Такое мнимое решение **позволяет на какой-то срок освободиться от насущных вопросов,** убрать их с рук долой, не думая о том, что они возникнут снова.

**И теперь о собаке.** Здесь обыгрывается само выражение с рук долой: **с рук убрали, зато на ногах оставили.** И что с этими проблемами делать? Да какая разница, зачем **сейчас** об этом думать? С ног их пусть хоть собака тащит, нам всё равно.

Так осуждается стремление людей уходить от проблем, решать их на короткое время, не думая о будущем.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем отрицательное. 
"Сошло с рук" - как сухим из воды вышел. 
"С рук долой" - говорит об избавлении от того, что тяготило или было нежеланным. 
"Нам только с рук долой, а с ног — хоть собака тащи" - на столько связаны по рукам и ногам, хоть собака **за нас** тащи.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/27390)

Comment: В названии темы "о значении" - я ответил на вопрос о значении.

Comment: @Нижегородец  Сойти с рук - это дословно  избавиться от  проблемы, но что в этом плохого? Почему-то это фраза чаще всего имеет такой негативный смысл (осуждение): им что угодно сходит с рук.  Или даже предупреждение для себя: мне это пока сошло с рук, но надо быть осторожнее. Вторая поговорка на эту же тему, тоже осуждение. Вероятно, о формальном  (кажущемся) избавлении от проблем, которые еще вернутся. Вот и надо разгадать образ собаки, с которой такое развитие событий как-то связано.

Comment: Сойти с рук. Если речь о преступнике, то "да" - звучит осуждение. Если о повесе, то это не осуждение, а удивление везению. Нам только с рук долой (невмоготу уже), а с ног - хоть собака тащи (ещё хуже).

Comment: "Нам только...- ...собака тащи" - мол, по рукам и ногам скованы, и хуже, что по ногам. "Собака тащи" - помощника надо, который за нас "притащит".